# Python, trying to instantiate class imported using __import__, getting ''module' object is not callable'

Tags: python, class, dynamic, import

I've been researching how to do this and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, I want to use **import** to import a class and then instantiate it and am doing it as so:

the class, from a file called "action_1", I have already imported / appended the path to this)

```
class Action_1 ():
    def __init__ (self):
        pass
```

how I am trying to import then instantiate it

```
imprtd_class = __import__('action_1', globals(), locals(), ['Action_1'], -1)

#instantiate the imported class:
inst_imprtd_class = imprtd_class()
>>>> 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__import__` returns the **module**, not anything specified in the `fromlist`. Check out the [`__import__` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) and see the example below.

```
>>> a1module = __import__('action_1', fromlist=['Action_1'])
>>> action1 = a1module.Action_1()
>>> print action1
<action_1.Action_1 instance at 0xb77b8a0c>
```

**Note**, the fromlist is not required in the above case, but if the `action_1` module was within a package (e.g. `mystuff.action_1`) it is required.  See the `__import__` docs for more info.

Comment: thanks for clearing this up, it works now, I hadn't realized that getattr was necessary in this case

Comment: @Rick: It's not.  It's just another way of doing it.  I've updated the answer... sorry for the delay, I'm a bit tired at the moment :)